# How work with preg_replace to replace with excluded pattern

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have some text contain html tags, I would like to replace all links with other one, but I want to replace just local links, not they start with http://
example :

```
<a href="local_link">test link</a> 
    ==> <a href="local_link_to_be_replace?url=local_link">test link</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com">Video</a> 
    ==> <a href="http://www.youtube.com">Video</a>
```

I try this preg_replace but not working :

```
$exclude = '<a href=\"http://.*?';
$pattern = '<a href=\".*?';
$content=preg_replace("~(($exclude)?($pattern))~i",'<a href="/action.php?url=$4',$content);
```

Thanks!

Comment: A little hint: You are referencing the fourth subpattern `$4` in your replace pattern, but actually there are only 3 since you opening three brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
$content = preg_replace('#<a href="([^:]*)">#i', '<a href="/action.php?url=$1">', $content);
```